# Change/Delete the square color when i clic on my Button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click, mahapps.metro

I have a question (With Metro Mahapp) :

How can I delete the black square around my button when I clic on ?

[image]

I want to delete the square or/and change his color !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPnsNWtKJtw

```
<Button
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
    Width="100"
    Margin="30,0,20,50"
    FontSize="25" 
    FontFamily="Cursive standard"
    Content="Retour" 
    Background="{x:Null}" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your button background transparent

```
<Button Background="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Nop, dosent work :/ its only when i clic on, its black. I think its a Metro Mahapp effect

Comment: is that all you have for the button? it has some effects

Comment: Yep I think, i use Metro Mahapp template :/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPnsNWtKJtw

Comment: did you try to set the background when you click the button to transparent?

Comment: How can i make that ?